# AngularJS: Unable to parse a list of JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

The following is the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
{[{"name":"Technology"},{"name":"Engineering"},{"name":"Business"}]}
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson
```

I'm getting the data from a service and saving it into the controller scope using the following:

```
vm = this;
vm.sectorList = response.data;
```

And my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="sector in ctrl.sectorList">
    {{sector.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON document. Remove the wrapping curly braces and you are good to go.

Comment: JSON is not properly formatted, should be this `{keyname:[{"name":"Technology"},{"name":"Engineering"},{"name":"Business"}]}`

Comment: The code in the service, where you handle the response, is probably more interesting than your controller. It would be helpful to include it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the curly braces before the `[]` in your JSON :

```
[{"name":"Technology"},{"name":"Engineering"},{"name":"Business"}]
```

Answer (score 11):

The JSON is invalid, hence the error you're getting. You're missing a key to go with the JSON array value. This for instance (key "anything" added) will work:

```
{"anything": [{"name":"Technology"},{"name":"Engineering"},{"name":"Business"}]}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the response is an array it should not be enclosed in curly brackets `{}`. This would be valid JSON:

```
[{"name":"Technology"}, {"name":"Engineering"}, {"name":"Business"}]
```

You are also trying to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on an object, when it takes a string as input parameter. If you want to make an object into a JSON string you should use  [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 5):

Your `JSON` is invalid you can validate your `JSON` [Here](http://jsonlint.com/)

It should be:

```
[{
    "name": "Technology"
}, {
    "name": "Engineering"
}, {
    "name": "Business"
}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to The JSON Validator

Answer (score 3):

Your key is missing.

```
{"YourKEY": [{"name":"Technology"},{"name":"Engineering"},{"name":"Business"}]}
```

You cannot access object of arrays without key.

Answer (score 3):

you need to assign the array to property of the object. can't assign array just inside of the object without property

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "name":"Technology"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Engineering"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Business"
      }
   ]
}
```

in the ng-repeat it should change as following

```
<div ng-repeat="sector in ctrl.sectorList.items">
    {{sector.name}}
</div>
```